# Can't find a list of possible date options

Tags: date

I have searched for two hours, probably 200 different pages trying to find a list of other date variable options.  I know "entry_date" and "current_time" and want to find some kind of "modification_date" or SOMETHING like that...to display that instead of "entry_date".  Does this exist?  I don't know what to call it, nor do I know how to search for it...I found the ExpressionEngine "Date Variable Formatting" but that's for the *format* of the variable.  Not a list of the variables themselves.  Someone please help me.  I'm going nuts!  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exp:channel:entries` tag has an `edit_date` variable. [Here are the docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#edit-date).

Comment: Thank you.  I wish Expression Engine made searching for answers easier.  I tried "modification_date" and "_date" and all kinds of things, never got there.  It worked exactly like what I'd hoped.  :-)